# jquery event for the multiple option selector

Tags: jquery, ajax

[image]

when i click on the arrow right name will show in right select option

[image]

i want to store the name which are in the right side for that i am doing serlization and i have used the code below

1. now which event should i use to call ajax is onchange is right?
2. nd i am selecting the option by

`var ser = $("#seo_keyword_select2_onchange").next().attr("select").serialize();
       var rowArr=decodeURIComponent(ser);`

my html is

```
<td id="seo_keyword_select2_onchange">
   <select name="seo_keyword_select2[]" id="seo_keyword_select2" multiple size="10"  class="multiple_select">
        <option value="0">Select 2</option>
    </select>
 </td>
```

but its not working now how to get this?

Comment: .next() selects the next TD, and .attr("select") returns undefined because td elements don't have a select attribute. selects don't have a select attribute either.

Comment: @KevinB this is return blank ,would you tell what to do

Comment: Could be: `var ser = $("#seo_keyword_select2_onchange select:first").serialize(); `

Comment: @AlexBall sir i need both name laxhmi,ganesh but i am getting only one at a time would you mind give me any suggestion or hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just use:

```
var ser = $('#seo_keyword_select2').serialize(); 
var rowArr = decodeURIComponent(ser);
```

Comment: thankyou sir,i need both name in right side but this is giving only one i have tried this

Comment: i have used the code do you know which event should i use to call ajax like i have used `change`

Comment: serialize() only take selected elements may be it is not want you want ? `$('#seo_keyword_select2').change(function () {
     $('#seo_keyword_select2 option').each (function () {
       alert( $(this).text() + " : " + $(this).val());`
       }
     );
});

Comment: thankyou for your help +1 for your last suggestion and code in comment

Comment: exactly, i want to send which is not selected but in the option would you tell me how to send this by ajax